# Hook value does not update in recurring call

Tags: javascript, react-native

I can see my state value being updated in useEffect, however, the value is still the same in a function that is being triggered every 5 seconds. Is there any way to resolve this?

```
const [check, setCheck] = useState(true);

// Button to toggle Check
const buttonToToggleCheckValue = () => {
    console.log("Toggle check");
    setCheck(!check);
};

// Call this function every 5 seconds
const triggeredEveryFiveSeconds = () => {
    console.log("Check value: " + check); 
};

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect Check value: " + check);
}, [check]);
```

```
---output---

Check value: true
Check value: true
Check value: true
Toggle check
useEffect Check value: false
Check value: true             <--- Value should be false
Check value: true
Check value: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that whenever the state changes your component gets re-rendered  and initialises the state as true. You can use useRef as shown in the below snippet.

```
const check = useRef(true);

  // Button to toggle Check
  const buttonToToggleCheckValue = () => {
    console.log('Toggle check');
    check.current = !check.current
  };

  // Call this function every 5 seconds
  const triggeredEveryFiveSeconds = () => {
    console.log('Check value: ' + check.current);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect Check value: ' + check.current);
  }, [check]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      triggeredEveryFiveSeconds();
    }, 5 * 1000);
  }, []);
```

ref will maintain the value over multiple renders.